# Using Sudo in Windows SFTP to switch user?

Tags: sftp, putty, windows-shell, switch-user

I am trying to upload files on my server using the PuTTY SFTP command shell.
My teammates have been using the Mac and Linux is our server, so they have predefined commands.

I am working on Windows and need to do the following (these are ssh commands on Mac for SFTP) :

```sh
# Copy from my laptop to my home directory  /home/username
# Change the permissions on your folder:  
chmod 777 /home/username # this is giving issues

# Change to the "ABC" user: 
sudo su gcnweb # this is not working in windows

cd /path../  # Go to the deployment directories //no issues here

cp /path of the director/ # Copy the files from your home dir to the deployment dir //no issues here
```

Please check above and if anyone can help me in workaround to the same in Windows using PuTTY SFTP.

Comment: It would help if you show us the "predefined" commands" the Mac users have.

Comment: I have ,mentioned them above, they are using the same..:)

Comment: Is the `cd` and `cp` supposed to run within the `sudo su` session? It cannot work like this. Is it a script file or a transcript of an interactive session? (i.e. do they paste this commands to a terminal window?)

Comment: Well, they are working and my teamates was doing it on his Mac, It works!! These are the commands they use in the terminal window.

Comment: So is it a script file or what?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the comment, please check the edited comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90593/discussion-between-iti-tyagi-and-martin-prikryl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are shell commands. It has nothing to with an SFTP.

You can execute the exactly same commands, if you use a Windows SSH client. Like PuTTY itself (`putty.exe`).

Comment: I am using the Putty>PSFTP, but there these are giving errors

Comment: Do not use PSFTP, use PuTTY.

Comment: It works, Thanks, accepting the answer